# Solidity: Call Deposit function with value

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have a deposit smart contract (Bank) below. I can use remix entering the value and calling the Deposit function.

How can i write a smart contract to do the same (Sender) below. I tried adding the interface but I cant seem to add a value when i call the sendDeposit

[image]

//// Bank Smart Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract bank {
    uint256 public amountIn;
    function deposit() external payable returns(uint256) {
        amountIn = msg.value ;
        return amountIn;
    }
}
```

///// SENDER Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface Receiver {

    function deposit() external payable returns(uint256);
}

contract sender {
    Receiver private receiver = Receiver(0x0fC5022f7B5c4Df39A836);

    function sendDeposit(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        receiver.deposit{value: _amount}();
    }


    receive() external payable {
         require(msg.value > 0, "You cannot send 0 ether");
    }

 }
```

I tried writing it like this, but there is no value in the transaction send

`function sendDeposit(uint256 _amount) public payable { receiver.deposit{value: _amount}(); }`

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry for being unclear. I would like to create a function with name SendDeposit in the Sender smart contract to call the function Deposit in the Bank smart contract.

The SendDeposit function should send value of _amount ETH and call the Deposit function in the Bank smart contract. 

The issue with current SendDeposit function is that 0 val gets sent although transaction is successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Bank {
    uint256 public amountIn;
    function deposit() external payable returns(uint256) {
        amountIn = msg.value ;
        return amountIn;
    }
    // receive() external payable{}
    function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}


interface Receiver {
    function deposit() external payable returns(uint256);
}

contract Sender {
    Receiver private receiver ;
    constructor(address _receiver){
        receiver=Receiver(_receiver);
    }

    function sendDeposit(uint256 _amount) public payable {
        receiver.deposit{value: _amount}();
    }

    receive() external payable {
         require(msg.value > 0, "You cannot send 0 ether");
    }

 }
```

1- Deploy the Bank contract first and copy the address

2- Deploy the Sender contract, passing the copied Bank contract

3- call `sendDeposit` from `Sender` contract, you need to pass same amout to function input and value input which is under the "Gas limit" input

4- transaction will be succcessful. call the `getBalance` from Bank contract